# How to vectorise iloc multiple conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying this in python 3.5.2 and pandas 0.18.1

Below is my sample data

```
    %busy   %queue
1   50      3.0
2   80      2.0
3   90      3.0
4   90      3.0
5   90      3.0
6   30      1.1
7   45      1.3
8   55      1.5
9   65      1.7
```

Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('cpu.csv')
total_row = df.shape[0]
for i in range(0, total_row):
  if df['busy'].iloc[i:i+3] >90 & df['queue'].iloc[i:i+3] => 3:
       print("High usage observed")
       break 
  else:
      continue
```

Output should be:

the if condition should evaluate True or False, if it is true,
print("High usage observed")

Note: The IF loop only become TRUE during the value of i=2, from i=2 to i=4,
%busy is greater than 90 and %queue is equal to 3, so the condition needs to satisfy and the print statement gets executed

My expectation is, the statement df['busy'].iloc[i:i+3] >90, should give either True or False
Similarly the second statement df['queue'].iloc[i:i+3] > 3, should be True or False

finally the if loop should be like, True & True, than the statement inside loops needs execute

But currently I am getting error as below
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: You shouldn't be iterating the df in the first place for this. Have you researched the issue? This is a very common error but harder to pin down as an exact duplicate.

Comment: Why was that your expectation? If you had read some of the introductory numpy/pandas materials, you would know that both of these libraries provide data-structures that support vectorized operations. And this includes the comparison operators.

Comment: That's bitwise and, which has high precedence. Use `and` instead.

Comment: Anyway, please add the expected output to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use vectorised calculations for this task.

Here's an example using [`np.minimum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.minimum.html) and [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html):

```
b = df['%busy']
q = df['%queue']

mask1 = np.minimum.reduce((b, b.shift(-1), b.shift(-2))) >= 90
mask2 = np.minimum.reduce((q, q.shift(-1), q.shift(-2))) >= 3

df['high_usage_marker'] = mask1 & mask2

print(df)

   %busy  %queue  high_usage_marker
1     50     3.0              False
2     80     2.0              False
3     90     3.0               True
4     90     3.0              False
5     90     3.0              False
6     30     1.1              False
7     45     1.3              False
8     55     1.5              False
9     65     1.7              False
```

Comment: The expectation is to analyze data, if the %busy >90 and %queue >3 for 3 consecutive iteration, than I need to report it as high utilization. I tried to find this in google, but find hard to get my needs.

Comment: your solution is something different than my expectation.

Comment: And therein lies the problem. Please **show** us your desired output. An explanation is great, but is no substitute for the *precise output your desire*. You are encouraged to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50571210/edit) your question with improvements.

Comment: your solution is something different than my expectation. you are doing one to one like, if busy[1] >90 and queue[1] >3 than True otherwise false. But my expectation is. if ([busy].iloc[1] > 90 & [busy]iloc[2] >90 & [busy]iloc[3] >90 ) & ([queue].iloc[1] > 3 & [queue]iloc[2] >3 & [queue]iloc[3] >3 ), if this is true, than print high utilization was observed, this will give single result either true or falsie, not series of true, false...

Comment: modified the question, added the output expected.

Comment: @RafiqShaikh, Nope, sorry, you've just copy-pasted your *explanation*. We need the *output*.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to do a *rolling* operation. For that, you can use `rolling()` function which is built-in in pandas `Series` objects.

Take an example:

```
df["status_busy"] = (df[::-1].busy.rolling(3).apply(lambda b: all(b >= 90))[::-1] *\
                     df[::-1].queue.rolling(3).apply(lambda q: all(q >= 3))[::-1]).fillna(0).astype(bool)



    busy    queue   status_busy
1   50  3.0         False
2   80  2.0         False
3   90  3.0         True
4   90  3.0         False
5   90  3.0         False
6   30  1.1         False
7   45  1.3         False
8   55  1.5         False
9   65  1.7         False
```

I inverted the values with `[::-1]` to do a forward-looking rolling operation. The default is backward-looking and to get that just remove the `[::-1]`